# Windows 7 Hangs once I click on Fonts icon in Control Panel

Tags: windows-7, fonts, bsod

Hi I had started getting random BSODs and I read elsewhere that it can be a font issue and it was suggested to restore the fonts on the computer to the default to fix it.

Previously the hangs where happening at random but now that i want to try this solution every time that i click on fonts icon in windows computer hangs. I have tried it around 10 times and with no exception if i click on fonts i will get a bsod with win32k.sys error that has page_fault_in_nonpaged_area and I get the code 0x00000050

Any other ways to restore the fonts aside from clicking fonts|and restoring from control panel?
I dont have the 64bit windows cds at the moment as the work place is shut down till 2nd of jan but i do have 32bit windows cdrom from my other computer...

Anyother help in dealing with this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you open c:\Windows\Fonts? If not, how many fonts are listed in that folder?

Comment: @Llamanerds Hi, i just tried using windows explorer to open c:\windows\fonts and it hanged and gave the same error. Then I checked using total commander and I can see there are 911 files in fonts folder and the last font modification has been a month a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to fix this myself. I just copied fonts from my other machine to a usb stick and then selected them once connected to the machine with BDOS and installed all the fonts and rewrote on the existing ones. after that BDOS stopped but to be on the safe side i went to control panel and fonts and then settings and restored the original windows fonts.